# Visual Composer doesn't load after inline script was added to the page on WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

how is it going?

I'm having some trouble with the visual composer for WordPress...
I was testing a widget, so I inserted some HTML and JS on an element inside the VC on  the Home, and Saved the Page. Everything look good on the output, but when I try to edit the page again through the Admin panel, I get errors refering to the Script previously added, and the VC does not load.

[image]

So, I can't open the element to remove the Script, and I can't seem to find this content anywhere on the database (searched wp_posts), so I can do it manually.

Anyone have ideas on how to possibly solve this?

I reeally didn't want to overwrite my database just to fix one page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if that script throws errors will block other scripts after it from running. What errors are thrown?

Comment: The errors are not really the problem, it was my mistake of pasting the script along with the HTML, so they are kind of expected. My main problem here is that I can't get to the content that was stored to erase that block.

Comment: can you restore an old revision of that page?

Comment: No, for whatever reason the Visual Composer does not return from a previous revision... Damn, I thought that it was going to work... -.- Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so my husband got it...
What he did was this:

1. Inspect the element of the Visual Composer disabled textarea, remove
   the class disabled.
2. The content showed up, not configured, but still.
3. Then, find the real textarea behind tinyMCE and its content.
   Beware that the content is all encoded, so you will not find any "
   or < or any HTML tags, so you better search for key words.
4. Remove the problematic part of the code, in my case, the script tag
   and Publish the page.

Problem solved. Without overwriting all database.

Thank you all for trying to help. :)